# Does inheritance maps to the single responsibility in S.O.L.I.D?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

As I learned the main OOP concept which maps to single responsibility principle is abstraction but let's say we have a completed software and some new requirements are needed so we can extend the existing classes without affecting them or adding new responsibilities to them (which is inheritance).So can we state that inheritance also maps and helps to the single responsibility principle. Please help me to clarify this argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Responsibility Principle is all about **cohesion**. You want to create classes that have a high degree of cohesion, meaning that the elements of a class are closely related to each other. The goal of this principle is to create classes that have only one responsibility, more specifically it should have only **one reason to change**.

Inheritance can indeed help to this principle but it depends on how you use it. There are a lot of ways on how to create classes that have only one reason to change, and generally, this is achieved by a lot of techniques of Object-Oriented Design, such as Composition, Inheritance, Interfaces, etc, there is no silver bullet to achieve it.

I would recommend checking the core [design patterns of OOP](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns), in order to get a better taste of how to add new responsibilities to an object. [Decorator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm) is a good example, where it uses Inheritance and Composition.